# How to sort a list based on index from its index dict?

Tags: python

For example:

```
words = ['this', 'test', 'a', 'is']

word_index_map = {'this':(1,5), 'is':(5,7),'a':(7,8), 'test': (11,15)}
```

word_index_map stores the start and end position of each word in the  text. I want to sort words based on their end position of each word, so that words will be sorted as:

```
words = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Their end position will be:

```
end_pos = [5, 7, 8, 15]
```

How to do this sorting? I am trying to do this:

```
def take_position(word, word_index_map):
    return word_index_map[word][1]

words.sort(key=take_position)
```

But this can't pass the word_dict into the take_position function, thus giving an error:
`TypeError: take_position() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word_index_map`'

Is there a way to pass the word_index_map to the function, or some other way  to sort it?

Comment: Yes, corrected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a lambda instead like

```py
words.sort(key=lambda word: take_position(word,  word_index_map))
```

Or instead of using your function you put the logic directly into the lambda

```py
words.sort(key=lambda word: word_index_map[word][1]
```

Comment: that looks very concise!